# Why linear-gradient won't work fine?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When it starts loading page, I see this image before it renders content for just a moment.
How can I fix this?

what do I need to check?

I'm using twitter-bootstrap.
There are navi, well, and fluid.

[image]

**CSS**

```
body { 
    min-width: 350px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(49, 57, 68);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(49, 57, 68), rgb(32, 37, 44));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Gradients act like background images, and by default repeat is on.

PS: the styles you have there are better suited on your navi element, not the body